# fast.ai course lesson 1: object has no attribute 'fine_tune'

Tags: python, fast-ai

I'm following the official course

Notebook For Lesson 1: https://www.kaggle.com/code/jhoward/is-it-a-bird-creating-a-model-from-your-own-data

Tutorial docs for the fast.ai vision library:
https://docs.fast.ai/tutorial.vision.html

this code:

```py
    dls = DataBlock(
        blocks=[ImageBlock, CategoryBlock],
        get_items=get_image_files,
        splitter=RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42),
        get_y=parent_label,
        item_tfms=[Resize(192, method='squish')]
    ).dataloaders(path, bs=32)

    learn = vision_learner(dls, resnet18, metrics=error_rate)
    learn.fine_tune(3)
```

results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Projects/fastai/l1-image-classification/l1_image_classification/build_model.py", line 39, in <module>
    build_model()
  File "/Projects/fastai/l1-image-classification/l1_image_classification/build_model.py", line 25, in build_model
    learn.fine_tune(3)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sys/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/l1-image-classification-ApaWH_9y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastcore/basics.py", line 496, in __getattr__
    if attr is not None: return getattr(attr,k)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sys/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/l1-image-classification-ApaWH_9y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1614, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'fine_tune'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what to suggest to you.  I've looked at the source, and there is certainly no `fine_tune` method in that class.  Maybe it's a version thing.  There is a "report issue" option on their web site.

Comment: it's working okay on my computer @TimRoberts! Unsure how /why

Comment: ```fine_tune(epochs, base_lr=0.002, freeze_epochs=1, lr_mult=100, pct_start=0.3, div=5.0, *, lr_max=None, div_final=100000.0, wd=None, moms=None, cbs=None, reset_opt=False, start_epoch=0) method of fastai.learner.Learner instance
    Fine tune with `Learner.freeze` for `freeze_epochs`, then with `Learner.unfreeze` for `epochs`, using discriminative LR.```

Comment: I've noticed you've substantially changed the example from the documentation. Have you tried actually running the examples top to bottom? What did you find?

Comment: @Mark, sorry I linked the docs, but not the official course Kaggle notebook that was I mostly working from. I added that link. BTW, I can copy the given notebook and the code runs in Google Colab, but if I setup a Python environment on my laptop which seems to have the same fastai library version 2.7.12  installed, i get the error described.

Comment: whereabouts are you running it? I funnily enough was running this in VSCode on Sunday

Comment: I setup a Python poetry environment and I run with `poetry run python build_model.py`. I use IDEs for convenience, but I have reproducible project configuration + virtualenvs + builds setup with command line tools.

Comment: I'm actually using the PyCharm IDE, I use VSCode frequently as well, but PyCharm results in the same error I get when I run via command line, and I consider the command line the real configuration that needs to work. If command line works and the IDE doesn't, then it's clearly an IDE problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for the `fine_tune` method in the fastai library: https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/b273fbb32d075ef1d6fd372687b5f56564cead9a/fastai/callback/schedule.py#L161

```
# %% ../../nbs/14_callback.schedule.ipynb 60
@patch
@delegates(Learner.fit_one_cycle)
def fine_tune(self:Learner, epochs, base_lr=2e-3, freeze_epochs=1, lr_mult=100,
              pct_start=0.3, div=5.0, **kwargs):
    "Fine tune with `Learner.freeze` for `freeze_epochs`, then with `Learner.unfreeze` for `epochs`, using discriminative LR."
    self.freeze()
    self.fit_one_cycle(freeze_epochs, slice(base_lr), pct_start=0.99, **kwargs)
    base_lr /= 2
    self.unfreeze()
    self.fit_one_cycle(epochs, slice(base_lr/lr_mult, base_lr), pct_start=pct_start, div=div, **kwargs)
```

Notice I call it a "method", but it's not defined on a class. Wonder what's up with that?

You see that `@patch` decorator?

Check out the definition of the `patch` function in the fastcore library: https://github.com/fastai/fastcore/blob/master/nbs/01_basics.ipynb

TLDR:

Try adding a `from fastai.callback.schedule import fine_tune` at the top of your file. Importing that function will "patch" it onto the `Sequential` class.

Comment: wow, that worked!!! That seems needlessly complicated as a library design, but it is what it is. Also it confuses my IDE, and it shows that import line as unused even though it's required. But you solved it. Thank you.

Comment: What a hot mess this library is. Seems like you can fix this today with `from fastai.vision.all import vision_learner` but if you try `from fastai.vision.learner import vision_learner` the method call doesn't work.  It's a shame that the course has so much to offer, but by ignoring python best practices they make it so difficult to deal with.